# Configure courier to forward certain mails to external addresses

Tags: debian, logs, email, forwarding, maildrop

I have a debian 6.0 server with courier/courier-mta set up and some local domains. Now I want to create some forwards for some email address that should go directly to external addresses as there are no local users for those addresses.

Eg. I have an address "peter@example.com" (its an example, I use a different address) and I want it to be redirected to "peter@test.test" and also some other addresses from "example.com" but to different target domains.

I tried to configure courier with the webadmin interface and registered "example.com" as a local domain. Then under the aliases section i added the full "peter@example.com" address (as there is no local account) and set "peter@test.test" as recipient - but it didn't work. When I sent to the user I get:

> The error that the other server returned was: 550 User  unknown

Then I read something about courier aliases and created a new file "example.com" under the couriercfgdir/aliases and added some email addresses and targets (e.g.: "peter@example.com: peter@test.test") and run the "makealiases" command but it didn't change anything. I still receive the same 550 error when sending mail to peter@example.com.

I thought maybe aliases is ignored as long as I don't use maildrop, so I changed the courier delivery options to use "maildrop" (and installed the courier-maildrop package), restarted the courier server but still no change.

And I also don't know where to find some sort of log file. /var/log/mail.log was last updated in june but I have received emails since then and I don't see any other logfile for courier.

Somehow it looks as if my aliases are ignored but I don't get why.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, but this requires a mailbox, create a dummy mailbox (/home/vmail/domains/mydomain/redir), and create a dot-courier file (/home/vmail/domains/mydomain/redir/.courier) with the following content:

> dest1@wherever.com
>
> dest2@wherever.com

And that's it, when you send a mail to redir@mydomain.com, it will be forwarded to dest1@wherever.com and dest2@wherever.com

Aliases can be used for local mail accounts.